# Saving cookies in Cypress without cy.session()

Tags: cookies, cypress

I am looking for some way how to save exact cookie in Cypress through whole test case.

Was using

`Cypress.Cookies.defaults({ preserve: 'cookie_name' })`

and

`Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('cookie_name')`

but this doesn't work anymore. And the new `cy.session()` is not working for me, because I use custom addresses per user and per new form.

Does anyone know of anything that works better than `cy.session()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use pattern of `cy.session()` is a bit opaque, but since it replaces the older cookie config it probably can be made to work.

I have seen a note somewhere that session is likely to be revamped shortly.

Since `Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('cookie_name')` is deprecated but still available, maybe use that until session mark 2 comes along.

Comment: So the `Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('cookie_name')` should still work normally? It's seems like it wont save my cookies.

Comment: I believe so, and you can easily test it. The docs say *In a future release, support for Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce() and Cypress.Cookies.defaults() will be removed.*

Comment: BTW if you want some help with session, maybe elaborate more on the issue with it.

Comment: And what is the best part of the code for the Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('cookie_name'), should I use it inside beforeEach or somewhere else.

Comment: I guess it depends on the test. `Cypress.Cookies.defaults({ preserve: 'cookie_name' })` is more universal.